# Javascript - writing image file to blob (html5 file api)

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-upload, blob

I'm working with a chrome extension to copy user selected files into the extension's filesystem. I'm not getting any errors, but when I try to view the image, it's broken. Here's an example of the code:

```
 this.create = function(obj, attr, calling_model){
// Get parent directory
fs.root.getDirectory(obj.type, {create: true}, function(dirEntry) {
  // Create file
  dirEntry.getFile(obj.type+'-'+obj.id+'-'+attr.name, {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
      fileWriter.write(attr.value);
    }, errorHandler);
    alert('just wrote a file to: '+fileEntry.toURL());
    // Update passed object
    obj[attr.name] = fileEntry.toURL();
    calling_model.update(obj);   
  }, errorHandler); 
}, errorHandler);

};
```

where attr.value = the value of a file input. I feel like I should be turning the value of the file input into a blob before writing it to the filesystem, but I haven't found any examples of how to do that. Has anyone tackled this problem before?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If `attr.value` is a `File` object, your code should work. I wrote a section on ["duplicating user selected files"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-user-selected) in my HTML5Rocks article on the Filesystem API that should help.